# Multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers being set

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

In my Node/Express app, I am specifically removing any existing Allow-Origin header, and setting it to a specific domain. It works locally, but on the server, it keeps saying that the response header contains multiple values. This is the only place I set these headers in the entire codebase. Any thoughts on where else could be setting this?

'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'https://*.mycompany, *', but only one is allowed.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.removeHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://*.mycompany.com'); 
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    if(req.method==='OPTIONS'){
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }
    next()
});
```

Comment: What do you mean *"existing Allow-Origin header"*? What other part of your server is adding that?

Comment: I'm referring to the first line in the app.use function, I remove the 'Access--Control-Allow-Origin' header

Comment: Yes, I can see that, but where do you think it's coming from to start with?

Comment: there is probably a reverse proxy in front of your server, and for convenience they are just setting cors headers on everything

Comment: Thanks for the idea - the issue was in the nginx config on the server being deployed to had the line:
                     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
...Though I'm surprised  our removeHeader() statement didn't remove it.

Comment: `removeHeader` is happening **before** Nginx handles the response (it must be, because Express is *creating* the response). If that's the problem it's not in the question, and the answer (that you've *accepted*) doesn't actually help anyone else with the same problem. I'd suggest either editing to include the Nginx config and writing your own answer that actually solves it, or unaccepting and deleting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this explains it for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMultipleAllowOriginNotAllowed. The problem is a browser will only accept one domain in an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header and you have a wildcard. The solution is to read the Origin header and echo that to Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the response if it's an Origin you want to allow.

Comment: That looks like a good point, however if I set it for localhost:4200, I have the same problem:
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:4200, *', but only one is allowed.

Comment: It ended up being a setting in our nginx config (see comment on my question). But your answer is correct.